# Como converter uma String em um id ou em um dado numérico?

Tags: java

Tenho strings que são únicas e gostaria à partir dela criar um id.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Creio que o método hashCode da String pode te ajudar. Você faz um loop em sua coleção de strings e chama esse método pra cada string, guardando o resultado como o id que você deseja.

Comment: Qual o seu objetivo? Hashes não geram valores únicos e cedo ou tarde pode haver colisão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método [hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) da classe String transforma a representação String em um número inteiro.

Exemplo em Java:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String[] strings = {"abc","def","ggh","rrt"};

    for(int i = 0; i < strings.length;i++)
        System.out.println(strings[i].hashCode());
}
```

Este código vai imprimir a seguinte sequência:

```
96354 //abc
99333 //def
102280 //ggh
113204 //rrt
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](http://ideone.com/P7eVcn).

Pergunta relacionada: [Usar hashcode como id é uma boa prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112754/3084)

Comment: exatamente isso que eu precisava, valeu.

Comment: Somente um aviso: hashes não geram valores únicos, isto é, pode haver colisão com o mesmo número sendo gerado por duas Strings diferentes. Então é importante para quem vier a usar hashes levar isto em consideração.

Comment: Sim @utluiz, isso realmente precisa ser levado em consideração. Um exemplo são as strings "Z@S.ME" e "Z@RN.E". Ambas geram o mesmo número inteiro. Portanto, depende do contexto ao qual está sendo aplicado. Existem outras funções hash, mas como você disse, não existe garantia de valores unicos.